# Return array of Property from Object Collection

Tags: c#

I have a class with this structure:

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public int Column4 { get; set; }   
}
```

and I have a collection of objects of this type call BusinessObjectCollection. If I want an array of values that are distinct for only Column2... what must I do?

What if I dont know the property that I need... so if i have ColumnTitle as a String... and whatever the value of ColumnTitle... I want the distinct values for that property

Comment: You mean you want to iterate over the collection (`List<BusinessObject>` I assume?) and find only those having different `Column2` value?

Comment: Yes... I know there is a way to write it using the Distinct function... but I don't know how

Comment: Luckily Jon came to the rescue.. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the result to be an `IEnumerable<BusinessObject>`, so that `Column2` is *only* used for implementing distinctness, there are two options:

- Implement `IEqualityComparer<BusinessObject>` in a way which uses `Column2`, and pass that into `Distinct`
- Use [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/):

  ```
  var distinct = original.DistinctBy(x => x.Column2);
  ```

Obviously the second is simpler, but it does require an extra library (or copying just the code for `DistinctBy`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of stuff that makes me really appreciate LINQ:

```
int[] distinctColumn2 = (from x in BusinessObjectCollection select x.Column2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: ok.. this is great! not what if I don't know which Column the user is passing? What if I have e.ItemProperty is being passed (now e.ItemProperty can have either Column1, Column2, Column3 or Column4)?

Comment: and e.ItemProperty returns a String

Answer (score 0):

Can use the pure LINQ distinct.

```
var result = (from bo in lbo select bo.Column2).Distinct();
```

Where lbo is a collection of BusinessObjects.

Regards.